# Why does Mathematica not display networks?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, visualization

Why does Mathematica not display (and export) the graph 'g' when n> 10000?

```
n = 10000;  g = RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[n, 1]]
```

ralph

Answer (score 5):

`Graph` objects render as a visual representation by default. This is merely for convenience, not a way to visualize the graph. If you want to explicitly visualize it, use [`GraphPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphPlot.html).

Once the graph gets large, visualization becomes expensive. I wouldn't want my work to be slowed down (or at worst: the notebook interface hang) when working with large graphs that I don't want to visualize at every step. It makes perfect sense that there is a limit on the graph size above which auto-visualization is not done. You can still use `GraphPlot` when necessary.

Comment: But the problem is that other functions don't work, for example: Association [(# -> PropertyValue [{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]) & / @VertexList [g]] If I use Graph [] also doesn't work.

Comment: @ralph your question was _"Why does Mathematica not display (and export) the graph?"_ and that was answered. If need to clarify your question, you can edit it, but if you are now asking something different you need to ask a new question.

Comment: @ralph - independent of the issue at hand, don't use `PropertyValue` to get the coordinates for each vertex, it would be more efficient to use `AssociationThread[VertexList[g] -> GraphEmbedding[g]]`